# Jquery animate with css masking

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, image-masking

I have been looking into animating an image background while using an image mask. I just dont know if its possible to use the image mask WHILE animating background color

[Example here -  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SptRr/205/)

What ideally i am looking for is to Have the background image(grains) NOT show thought into the glass image while the blue color(water) is filling the cup.

Also since using the image mask i now am able to see the entire `<div>` filling with the blue color. Any way to not see that either? I want to have the glass image overlayed onto the background while im able to have the blue color fill the cup.

Comment: Where is the mask that will suppress the water outside the glass?

Comment: @mvw Ahhh is that what im missing?

Comment: @mvw `.element` contains the a mask for the inner area of the cup

Comment: @mvw Thats what currently shows, but i want to mask out the blue part of the block OUTSIDE of the glass and NOT show the grains inside the glass

Comment: I see no effect of that mask image here - did you check its transparency channel?

Comment: Thinking i need multiple masks, one to mask out the grains from the glass and one to mask out the blue box from the outside of the glass. Then use z-index to layer them accordingly?